# How to scrape large amount of followers without hitting the twitter API limit

Tags: tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have been trying to get the followers details of an account with 800k followers but the issue is i am getting the api limit after few hundred followers below is my code can anyone optimize it a bit. I got only 360 followers and hit the limit for 15 minutes window.

```
def handleErrors(cursor):
    while True:
        try:
            yield cursor.next()
        except tweepy.TweepError:
            time.sleep(20 * 60)

for user in handleErrors(tweepy.Cursor(api.get_followers,screen_name='adl440').items()):
    print(user.screen_name)
```

Comment: Are you authenticated when you scrape? IIRC there are different API limits on the different "levels" you use to access the Twitter API.

Comment: Yes I am authenticated.